# Sun Mar 07 00:17:07 PST 2021 to mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, datetime, ssis

I am trying to load data from an Excel source where the date column has data like `Sun Mar 07 00:17:07 PST 2021` and I need to load it to SQL table with date-time data type and my value supposed to be in the following format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. Please let me know the solution.

Excel Source Data:

```
Sun Mar 07 00:17:07 PST 2021
```

SQL Destination Table with datetime column:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: From your Excel Source to the OLE DB Destination, double click the line between them and in the "Data Flow Path Editor" that pops up, click on the Metadata tab and edit your question to include the "Data Type" for your Excel date column.

Comment: If your target column is of type `datetime` then it has no specific format - you just need to a datetime data type

Comment: `Sun Mar 07 00:17:07 PST 2021` is - as far as I know - no valid date format at all, so I guess you will have to handle this on your own, e.g. in a script transformation. One way might be to split the string by " " (space character), "translate" it on your own and build a new date-string from it which can then be converted. So, e.g. "Sun" can be ignored, "Mar" is translated to "03", "07" stays as it is, the time stays as it is, "PST" is again ignored and "2021" stays as it is - these components can then be rearranged and converted.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nick.McDermaid mention in the comments, dates are not stored as strings in SQL Server,  so the DateTime columns have no formats.

To convert a `Sun Mar 07 00:17:07 PST 2021` to a DateTime value, you can use the following derived column expression (assuming that the column name is `StringDate`):

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([StringDate],9,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([StringDate],5,3) + "-" + RIGHT([StringDate],4) + SUBSTRING([StringDate],11,9))
```